# Why does UICollectionView log an error when the cells are fullscreen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` where my `itemSize` is the size of the `UICollectionView`. Basically, this is a line layout of cells where each cell is fullscreen and scrolls horizontally.

In my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass, I have overridden `prepareLayout` as follows:

```
- (void)prepareLayout {
    self.itemSize = self.collectionView.frame.size;
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero;
    self.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero;
}
```

The `UICollectionViewController` is very basic returning 10 items in one section. I've included a [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/w5mith/FullScreenCollectionViewLineLayoutErrorExample) for more detail.

Everything appears to be set up correctly. It looks right in the simulator and on the device but, when the collection view is displayed, there is an error logged to the console:

> ```
> the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
> the item height must be less that the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
> ```

*Note also that the collection view controller in my example is in a navigation controller and while that doesn't look particularly necessary in the example, in my real-world case I need the collection view in a navigation controller.*

Comment: if you want to keep the scrollViewInsets managed then just return the collecitonView height and width minus the content inset and safeAreaInsets.  So height = collectionView.frame.size.height - collectionView.contentInset.top - collectionView.safeAreaInsets.top - collectionView.safeAreaInsets.bottom and same with width.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There is a property on `UIViewController`–`automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`–that defaults to `YES`. This means that when a `UIViewController` has a `UIScrollView` in its view hierarchy–which is true of a `UICollectionViewController`–the `contentInset` property of that scroll view is adjusted automatically to account for screen areas consumed by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar.

The documentation for that property states:

> **automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets**
>
> Specifies whether or not the view controller should automatically adjust its scroll view insets.
>
> `@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to adjust its scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO if you want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as
>   when there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.

The solution is to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO` somewhere in your `UICollectionViewController` subclass, such as in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

I have put an [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/w5mith/FullScreenCollectionViewLineLayoutErrorExample) that illustrates this problem and solution. There are two branches: `with_error` and `fixed_error`. Here is a [diff of the change on GitHub](https://github.com/w5mith/FullScreenCollectionViewLineLayoutErrorExample/compare/with_error...fixed_error).

Comment: I'd have made it "up" twice if I could. Also, NOTE that you can change `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` right in the Interface Builder.

Comment: damn...thanks for that. I was really hitting my head hard!

Comment: My collection view is one of a table view cell's subviews, this solution is not working for my situation.

Comment: @nikans I can't see such an option in interface builder, I am using UICollectionView in UIViewController.

Comment: @Mansuu.... Select your ViewController. In the Inspector it's "Attributes" tab where you will find it under "View Controller" section

Comment: Thanks @nikans, yeah I found that, but still the same problem.

Comment: I face this problem only when I load image.

Comment: automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is deprecated. Use contentAdjustmentBehaviour on the scrollView instead.

Answer (score 20):

**iOS 11 update:** `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is deprecated in iOS 11.0.

Apple recommends using `UIScrollView`'s `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` method instead. I set this value to `.never` and the error has gone. You can also set this property in Interface Builder.

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: I tried this and it is a hack that causes the cells to animate in funny ways while scrolling. I do not recommend this. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53806783/347339) for what worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

This issue just occured to me on 3x screens (namely the iPhone 6 Plus.) As it turned out, the autolayout engine did not really like long floating point values (such as .33333333), so my solution was to `floor` the return height in `sizeForItemAt:indexPath:`.

```
return CGSize(width: preferredWidth, height: floor(preferredHeight))
```

Comment: Interesting case. Maybe then it makes sense to also apply `floor` to width?

Comment: @Legonaftik Yes, that's probably a good idea in other cases, but in this question, the cells are full width and the width of the screen in logical pixels is always a whole number.

Comment: Legendary answer... fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem when rotating the device from portrait to landscape, back to portrait. You want to invalidate the `collectionView`'s layout upon device rotation and before the call to super, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    // Causes collection view cells to be resized upon orientation change.
    // Important that this is called *before* call to super in order to prevent error from being logged to console.
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This way had worked for me perfectly!.

I just subtracted the top and bottom insets from the view's height as said in that error.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height - (view.safeAreaInsets.top + view.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Be careful - this code would only work fine of the `UICollectionView` takes the whole space of `self.view`

Answer (score 5):

If you have collectionView inside scrollView just put .invalidateLayout method inside viewDidLayoutSubviews as shown below:

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

I found out that .invalidateLayout method inside viewWillTransitionToSize doesn't change collection view bounds on orientation change in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

A fix that worked for me.

`collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = .zero`

or do it via IB:

`Estimated Size: None`

If you create the collection view in the IB, the `Estimated Size` property (`estimatedItemSize`) is set to `Auto`. The docs say it's `.zero` by default but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

[Like Stunner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53806783/347339), I had the same problem when rotating from landscape (picture using full width) to portrait mode. His suggestion was the only one which really helped.

Attached the code with latest Swift for his ObjC example ... and as a bonus, my code to find the center cell of the collection view. Works quite nice ;-)

```
/**
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 viewWillTransition()

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    // find cell in the center of the screen and store it in a global variable
    let center = self.view.convert((self.collectionView!.center), to: self.collectionView)

    // get the indexPath for the cell in the center of the current screen
    if let index = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: center) {

        // store it in a class property
        self.indexPathOfCenterCell = index
    }

    // force recalculation of margins, borders, cell sizes etc.
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

    // inform UIKit about it    
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ios 10: topmost view was not connected to the view outlet

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to embed a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableView`. I was generating a new `UICollectionView` in each `UITableView` cell, but I did not put any constraints on the height of that `UICollectionView`. So, when I put a constraint on the height, that error is gone!

Comment: If someone else would try to achieve a similar UI behaviour, I would recommend to take a look at Compositional Layout introduced at WWDC 2019: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout. Even though it's available only for iOS 13+, you can still use this wrapper to make it available for older iOS versions: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/IBPCollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had property

```
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

set in my flow layout. So I had to switch it to some obviously wrong constant (but with some explicit height) to suppress this warning.

UICollectionView is such a thing-in-itself and sometimes absolutely unpredictable

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.

After load cell which is full width and some height of screen. on some condition I changed the height of cell then I was getting the same error

to fix this

I used

```
   func updateHeightPerRatio(with image:UIImage) {
    let ratio = collectionView.bounds.width / image.size.width
    constHeightCollectionView .constant =  ceil(image.size.height * ratio)
    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (completed) in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Solution is reload data then perform batchupdate with that collection view re -calculate the frames . after that reload collectionview again it will apply calculated frames to cell

And now there is no log for issue now.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to reduce bottom inset (from 20 to 0) of cell as I have reduced 20 from height of collectionview 
From

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
-        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 20, right: 10)
+        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
     }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 350, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height - 20)
        return size
    }
```

Comment: I bet that in yours case it would be possible to make the height of the items to be up to `collectionView.bounds.size.height - 30`. Note that before making the change the total vertical inset of content was `10 + 20 = 30`. After the change it's `10 + 0 = 10` - so no magic here :)