# Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm using a `tableView` with `collectionsView` inside cells.

When I scroll `tableView`, this message appears in console:

> NameOfProject[1108:15021] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout
>   instance is , and it is
>   attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {3750,
>   210.66666666666666}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: . 2018-05-03
>   08:47:52.190847-0300
>
> NameOfProject[1108:15021] Make a symbolic breakpoint at
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the
>   debugger.

I created a symbolic breakponit, but it doesn't stop in code..
Someone can help me to find a way to remove this warning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be a problem with floating point sizes. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626835/3151675

Comment: It didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to check your methods

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And try to update the views with constraints referenced depending on each case.

```
@IBOutlet weak var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

With errors like that you should give screenshots of your view on Storyboard to get better help and try to explain a bit more.

Hope it helps.